# Intro book bridging calculus and physics

Tags: calculus, reference-request, physics

A bit of background: I'm participating in a Maths course that now introduced Calculus, mostly basic differentiation and integration.

In the course there are quite a few motion related problems, that is, problems involving velocity, acceleration, etc. and how those relate to the first/second derivative.

The course also includes an intro on vector geometry in up to three dimensions.

I did ok solving the problems but struggle to get an actual understanding of the topics, beyond applying formulas. I feel that some basic knowledge in physics could help me getting a better grip on Calculus and also vectors.

I already have the book Calculus by Spivak for self study which I really enjoy (although it's very hard for me), but it focuses more on the theory (which I enjoy more.)

I'm looking now for some book that can help me connecting the more applied side of Calculus of vectors/motion, where I'm really not that strong. The level should be,a as I mentioned, beginner Calculus and I don't know much about Physics so far. Maybe that's why I'm struggling.

Any recommendations welcome.

Comment: Maybe just a freshman physics book like Giancoli would be useful.

Comment: @littleO Thanks, that looks like a solid recommendation, will check it out!